# Device randomly restarts and has battery drain after .apk file installation

Tags: battery-life, reboot, apk, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I'm **developing** an Android app, and at the moment I let to install as an **.APK file** from my webpage to my close friends.

On the device of one of them, the installation causes an error and the App **doesn't got installed**. But since that moment his device **restarts without any sense** and has a **hight battery drain**.

- My App needs 2 permissions: "**full network access**" and "**control vibration**".
- App worked well on devices whith API's from 16 to the last

The device specifications are:

- Samsung galaxy III mini
- version **4.1.2** (not rooted)

**What can I do with the device?**
**Is my apk able to cause this issues?**

*(I really need help to solve this issue fast. Sorry for my English, please edit any misspelling, thanks)*

Comment: After looking arround, I think there's not any problem with tha app. It seems a coincidence and battery becomes dead. When he replace it, we will know.